# Calculate max value of list of numbers with a maximum combination of "x"

Tags: mysql, sql, math

ok, i'm not sure if i can explain this right. 
Lets say i have a table with three columns (id, price, maxcombo)

1. maybe there's like 5 rows in this table with random numbers for price.  2.  id is just incremental unique key)
2. maxcombo specified if that price can be in a combination of up to whatever number it is.

If x was 3, i would need to find the combination that has the maximum value of the sum 1-3 columns.

So say the table had:

1 - 100 - 1
2 -  50 - 3
3 -  10 - 3
4 -  15 - 3
5 -  20 - 2

the correct answer with be just row id 1.

since 100 alone (and can only be alone based on the maxcombo number)
is greater than say 50 + 20 + 15 or 20 + 15 or 10 + 20 etc.

Does that make sense?

I mean i could just calculate all the diff combinations and see which has the largest value, but i would imagine that would take a very long time if the table was larger than 5 rows.

Was wondering any math genius or super dev out there had some advice or creative way to figure this out in a more efficient manner.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I have formed an SQL statement that can resolve this problem. However, how do you plan to input X into it anyway?

Comment: i'm thinking a input parameter for a stored proc. But i would love to see the SQL statement you came up with either way if possible without the X input.  Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated!

Comment: However, after making it I noticed you wrote "I could calculate the combination and see which has the largest value", but you didn't post any SQL snippet about how you would do it. Then, there's no warranty that my approach will be better, but here goes...

Answer (score 0):

I built this solution to achieve the desired query. However, it hasn't been tested in terms of efficiency.

Following the example of colums 1-3:

```
SELECT max(a+b+c) FROM sample_table WHERE a < 3;
```

#### EDIT:

Looking at:

> The correct answer will be just row id 1

...I considered maybe I misunderstood your question, and you want the query just obtain the rowid. So, I made this other one:

```
SELECT a FROM sum_combo WHERE a+b+c=(
    SELECT max(a+b+c) FROM sum_combo WHERE a > 3
);
```

Which would for sure take too long in larger tables than just 5 rows.